# Codeigniter: Image Upload

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I have a large form, and I just added an file input to allow users to upload an image.

Here's the new HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file_1" />
<input type="text" name="image_description_1" class="text-input"/>
```

Here's the new _submit function:

```
if($this->CI->input->post('file_1')){
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 2000;
    $config['upload_path'] = realpath(APPPATH . '../assets/uploads/avatars');

    $this->CI->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->CI->upload->do_upload();

    $image_data = $this->CI->upload->data();

    $image['description'] = $this->CI->input->post('image_description_1');
    $image['user_id'] = $id;
    $image['image'] = $image_data['file_name'];

    $this->CI->db->insert('report_images',$image);

}
```

The description and user_id are correctly getting submitted, but the file is lost.

Should I be doing something different?  Not really sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all don't get the `do_upload()` for granted, you have to validate the [upload](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html):

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('file_1'))
{
    // something went wrong, display errors
}   
else
{
    // everything is fine
}
```

Also, most likely it's your `upload_path`, check the document I linked to:

```
//You'll need a destination folder for your uploaded images. Create a folder at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and set its file permissions to 777.  
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

So you may need to change your setting to something like:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/avatars/';
```

Comment: Ahh! I'm getting 'you did not select a file to upload'...I've tried this with both `form_open` and `form_open_multipart`.  Again, db values are getting entered, just no upload.  Could it have to do with my filepath?

Comment: first of all **OF COURSE** you need to use `form_open_multipart`! also, where is your assets folder? outside the system folder? what is your folder structure?

Comment: application, assets, and system are at the root.

Comment: @Kevin Brown: ok so, `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/avatars/';` should work?

Answer (score 4):

codeigniter expects your file input to be named userfile, unless you specify in your code like this,

```
$field_name = "some_field_name";
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
```

Comment: I changed my html `name="userfile"`.  Still no luck.

Comment: can you add this to your code in place of `$this->CI->upload->do_upload()` 'if(!$this->CI->upload->do_upload()){$this->CI->upload->display_errors();}`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the problem is. But May be the below links could help you.

[Upload file bug in codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/113029/)

Also you can initialize the config to set preferences.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

[File Uploading class in codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of the input file is set to "userfile" because the upload function expects the files coming from an input field whose name is set to "userfile"