# uploading an image in codeigniter trouble

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, upload

I have a code from the tutorial and i dont know what happen's why mine doesn't work. I just follow the tutorial and the code doesn't work. I am using a codeigniter framework, please help me with these, i have no error in console also, i dont know what's happening why . Also it doesn't sends a request from ajax. Please check the code in ajax. Thanks.

ajax code:

```
$(function () {
  var inputFile = $('input[name=file]');
  var uploadURI = $('#form-upload').attr('action');

  $('#upload-btn').on('click', function(event) {
     var fileToUpload = inputFile[0].files[0];
     if(fileToUpload != 'undefine') {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", fileToUpload);
        $.ajax({
            url: uploadURI,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentData: false,
            success: function(data) {
              alert("Profile picture updated!");
            }
        });
     }
  });
});
```

from view :

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url("profile/profile_picture") ?>" id="form-upload">            
              <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
                <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>
                <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> Select file</span><input type="file" name="file"></span>
                <a href="#" id="upload-btn" class="input-group-addon btn btn-success fileinput-exists"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open"></i> Upload</a>
              </div>
            </form>
```

controller:

```
public function profile_picture() {
        $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/uploaded_images/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload("file")) {

        }
        else {
            echo "File cannot be uploaded";
        }
    }
```

i got this error : [image]

```
File cannot be uploadedarray(1) {
      ["error"]=>
      string(43) "<p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>"
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter: Image Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684612/codeigniter-image-upload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the problem is it should be '`contentType`' not '`contentData`'. Here is updated JS code

```
$(function () {
    var inputFile = $('input[name=file]');
    var uploadURI = $('#form-upload').attr('action');

    $('#upload-btn').on('click', function(event) {
        var fileToUpload = inputFile[0].files[0];
        if(fileToUpload != 'undefine') {
            var formData = new FormData($('#form-upload')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: uploadURI,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("Profile picture updated!");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i have a problem why does the code doesn't go with ajax. it doesnt send data. it doesnt execute my controller

Comment: I think your formData  not constructed correctly. I have edited my comment and given a link. You can follow this and paste updated code if your problem doesn't fix

Comment: can you fix my code posted ? still its more likely similar

Comment: 1. Check in browser console, is there any error
2. after/before formData.append("file", fileToUpload); add another line formData.append("action", uploadURI);

Comment: hello sir. i got success in console but  in response i got this : File cannot be uploaded

Comment: add var dump for example profile_picture() { var_dump($_POST) and provide the print.

Comment: what would i vardump sir ?

Comment: before upload code write var_dump($_FILE); and var_dump($_POST); it will say whats submitted through form

Comment: i dont understand sir. i got these: array(272) {
  ["-----------------------------45661633911626
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(1195) ""file"; filename="14620082_120300000508885579_630840128_n.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

�����JFIF����������Photoshop 3.0�8BIM�����g(�bFBMD01000aaa03000060210000fd40000060450000364a0000b4590000918d0000449400003c9b000080a20000f6190100
���ICC_PROFILE���lcms��mntrRGB XYZ �����)�9acspAPPL����������������������������������-lcms
��������������������

Comment: Ok got it. Update this line $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; to  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';

Comment: it doesnt solve the problem sir still i got that error and in the last message it says file cannot be upload

Comment: :) no worries. add this line $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); var_dump($error); just before the line echo "File cannot be uploaded";

Comment: here is the reply sir : File cannot be uploadedarray(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(43) "<p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>"
} why ? i already selected

Comment: What is your browser version? Check it supports FormData api

Comment: mozilla firefox sir

Comment: mozille firefox version no?

Comment: Firefox 49.0.2 sir

Comment: Strange. last try. if it doesn't work I will update you later. remove this two line var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", fileToUpload); and use this two line var form = $('form')[0]; 
var formData = new FormData(form); instead

Comment: Here is the error sir:
array(2) {
  ["-----------------------------143481563120748

Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(57) ""q"





-----------------------------143481563120748--

"
  [0]=>
  string(57) ""q"





-----------------------------143481563120748--

"
}
File cannot be uploadedarray(1) {
  ["error"]=>
  string(43) "<p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>"
}

Comment: sorry John, I tried my best. I will test your code later in my computer. Meantime if you can solve this let me know please. Best of luck. You can inbox me too

Comment: thnks sir... Okay sir

Comment: @JcJohn I have edited my solution. Please check and let me know it works or not

Answer (score 0):

You can my thread that , i gave the solution for multiple images upload using ajax , its quite easy just remove the array from name of my solution , then you will get your image in controller .

here's the link of solution of mine .
[getting error while uploading image via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582426/getting-error-while-uploading-image-via-ajax/40583329#40583329)

Comment: i want only 1 file to be uploaded sir

Comment: as i said remove the array from input field of file

Comment: in controller , get the only image .